# writing liberty logs directly to graylog

Tags: logging, docker, graylog

i am running a liberty appserver container. How can I make sure that all the appserver logs (messages.log,console.log,ffdc,etc) goes directly to graylog and is not written at all in the appserver container?Note tha central idea here is that logs should never be written inside container as it would keep on eating memory and increase container size over time. Also we have limitation of not using data volumes.

Comment: Start by checking the Websphere Liberty documentation about logging: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Answer (score 0):

As such I did not find any exact solution. Going with log rotation.